# Trade off with declaring method synchronized in java?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, volatile, synchronized

I had a problem with a thread locking up for some still unknown reason in my Android App whenever I tried to kill Thread B from Thread A (usually, sometimes it worked).  I guessed that it was because some of my methods were making calls across the threads without being synchronized.  I made the cancel method and a lot of methods that were essentially event handlers synchronized and made a few shared variables volatile and everything worked.

I don't know which among the 20 odd volatile/synchronized declarations I added actually solved the problem, and that got me thinking "Should I care? It works don't mess with it!"

So, my question is: **Is there any trade off associated with declaring a method synchronized or a primitive volatile?  Is there any reason to avoid these declarations if they are not needed?**

**Edit**
The thread(s) in question is a Bluetooth connection that is receiving/sending streaming data, so ASyncTask and other worker thread type solutions don't work well.  They are designed for performing a finite task and terminating when done.  Some, like ASyncTask, also add a lot of overhead that simply kills the app.  For continuously running threads like this, using a Thread is still the best way to do it.

I am using an android [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to generate and manage the threads so I am following Android design paradigms in that respect.

Comment: There's a (small?) inherent performance penalty. It's hard to tell what the "problem with a thread locking up" was (polling a non-volatile member field?), but liberally adding `synchronized` sounds like a good way to get a deadlock, and how do you know your app is free from race conditions? The big issue is that you have a *lot* of shared state between threads — you need to decide what needs to be shared, make sure shared state is thread-safe (making as much as possible immutable helps), and decide how threads communicate (a Handler/ConcurrentLinkedQueue/LinkedBlockingQueue?).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it work don't fix it for now :), but for the next project you should consider using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html). I don't think the performance impact isn't of real concern in Android context, but the complexity, readability and future maintainability can be a problem (cancel/kill thread, many shared variables).

Comment: I know about ASyncTask, but this is a Bluetooth Communication application which requires a constantly running thread.  ASyncTask is meant for a single task that will end at a finite time in the future, not a stable connection.  ASyncTask is great but it's not a magic bullet.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know in where do you use it, but based on '20 odd volatile/synchronized' is still quite complex for a Java program.

Comment: For background Bluetooth communications, shouldn't you be doing it as an ongoing service instead?  Let the Android system manage your service's thread, and have your application talk to the service.

Comment: @Fluffy I am running it in a service, but services aren't themselves separate threads.  They run on the UI thread and need to spin off other threads to do their work.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#WhatIsAService

Comment: Okay, clearly I was mistaken about how much Android did automatically for Services.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience it's generally easier and often more performant to do your locking at as fine-grained a level as possible, using synchronized(object){...} for accesses to a particular object.  Also, if there are several locks that you have to acquire at the same time, ALWAYS make sure that you're always acquiring them in the same order.

Static methods have their own chunk of weirdness to worry about; a synchronized instance method will only be synchronized to that instance, not to the class as a whole, and so if you need to synchronize to both in an instance method you'll need to do something like  synchronized(this.class){...} as well, although if you're applying the above, really you'd just be doing synchronized() over the static fields that you're accessing in the particular method.

As another note, in general you don't want to be spawning your own threads, and instead should use the system's pre-existing mechanisms for thread management (such as ThreadPoolExecutor for ongoing work queues or AsyncTask for asynchronous UI updates).  ThreadPoolExecutor tends to be more performant (and can better leverage multi-core devices), but you have to do some extra work if it's going to do things to the UI; AsyncTask, on the other hand, tends to be a bit slower and more heavyweight but it also runs its onPostExecute callback in the UI thread.

Comment: All of those methods (ThreadPool, ASyncTask, etc) are designed to run a task or some form of heavy processing that will terminate when the work is done.  I'm managing an active bluetooth connection and sending dozens of different data packets and monitoring lots of connection states and variables.  For a non-terminating process like this, ASyncTask and worker threads are not the proper choice.

Comment: Okay. My third paragraph was more as a general rule of thumb and not specific to your question as edited, but it's still something to keep in mind in general.